# Hostname to valid URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, dns, hostname

Is there an elegant way to convert a hostname/domain into a valid http url like so:
`example.com` to `https://example.com` ?

My current approach is something like:

```
const domainToURL = (domain: string) => {
  if (!domain.startsWith('http')) domain= `https://${domain}`;
  return new URL('/', domain).origin;
};
```

I'm sure there is something more robust out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use: Create a dummy [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object, change the [`.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hostname) property, then read the [`.href` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/href). Like this:

```js
function hostnameToURL(hostname) {
  // the inital value of the URL object can be anything
  const url = new URL("https://example.com");
  url.hostname = hostname;
  return url.href;
}

console.log(hostnameToURL("google.com"));
console.log(hostnameToURL("a.fun.website.com"));
console.log(hostnameToURL("example.com"));
```

If you need to take in more parameters (like specifying HTTP or HTTPS), you can easily tweak the function to do so. I find this approach better because you hand off all the work to the browser.

Comment: so your code assumes that the input will be a hostname. It won't work if the parameter already contains a scheme (for instance `https://google.com`). If you are sure you get a hostname in input you could just return `https://${hostname}`, I am not sure to understand why you bother with a new URL + href